# Replacing date in log files with file name with python

Tags: python

According to all of your comment, I modified as below

```
For example:
Let say there are 3 log files in a folder, which are 20190626.txt, 20190625.txt, 20190624.txt

The log format like below and let says all the content in the txts are the same:
2019-06-26 server2 rcd[308]: Loaded 12 packages in 'ximian-red-carpet' 20190626
2019-06-26 server2 rcd[308]: id=304 COMPLETE Download 20190626
2019-06-26 server2 rcd[308]: Unable to downloaded licenses info 20190626
2019-06-26 server2 /USR/SBIN/CRON[6808]: (root) CMD ( /usr/lib/sa/sa1 ) 20190626
2019-06-26 server2 /USR/SBIN/CRON[6837]: (root) CMD ( /usr/lib/sa/sa1 ) 20190626

And I want to replace "2019-06-26" according to the file name which are "20190625", "20190624", but replaced in "2019-06-25", 2019-06-24" and so on.

Then in 20190624.txt, the content will become:
2019-06-24 server2 rcd[308]: Loaded 12 packages in 'ximian-red-carpet' 20190624
2019-06-24 server2 rcd[308]: id=304 COMPLETE Download 20190624
2019-06-24 server2 rcd[308]: Unable to downloaded licenses info 20190624
2019-06-24 server2 /USR/SBIN/CRON[6808]: (root) CMD ( /usr/lib/sa/sa1 ) 20190624
2019-06-24 server2 /USR/SBIN/CRON[6837]: (root) CMD ( /usr/lib/sa/sa1 ) 20190624
```

And do the rest of logs in the file in the same way

Currently, I only can think of the logic, that is

1. for file in directory,
2. Open file,
3. Save the file name (YYYYMMDD),
4. Change the YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD,
5. Replace all the “2019-06-26” with "YYYY-MM-DD" and "20190626" with "YYYYMMDD" in all the log files
6. Save the files

For the code, I tried as below:

```py
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import re
    import os
    import sys
    import string

    mylist = os.listdir('C:/Users/xxx')
    length = len(mylist)
    olddate = '2019-06-26'

    for i in range (0, length - 1):
        newfilename = mylist[i]

        with open(newfilename) as f:    
            newdate = newfilename <<<< This is wrong, because newfilename is "2019062X.txt", but I want it to be "20xx-xx-xx" according to the file name    
            rtext=f.read().replace(olddate, newdate)                    
        with open(newfilename,"w") as f:
            f.write(rtext)
```

Thank you for you help!!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what your desired output should looke like. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: first do it for one file and later use `for-loop` to do it for many files.

Comment: Are there any other dates inside each of your log files? Or just the one (incorrect) date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use regular expression using in python the re module.

In order to replace text using regular expression use the re.sub function:

```
import re
'''old file data'''
oldfilename = "20480824.txt"
oldtext = " \nblabla foo 2048-08-24 this \n\
2048-08-24 foo bar \n\
2048-08-24: Socket created..."

'''new file data'''
newfilename = "20481023.txt"

'''compute new file data'''
olddate = re.sub(r'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.txt', '\g<1>-\g<2>-\g<3>', oldfilename)
newdate = re.sub(r'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.txt', '\g<1>-\g<2>-\g<3>', newfilename)
newtext = re.sub(r'{}'.format(olddate), '{}'.format(newdate), oldtext)

print("---olddate : " + olddate)
print("---newdate : " + newdate)
print("---oldtext : " + oldtext)
print("---newtext : " + newtext)
```

output is:

```
---olddate : 2048-08-24                                                                                                                              
---newdate : 2048-10-23                                                                                                                              
---oldtext :                                                                                                                                         
blabla foo 2048-08-24 this                                                                                                                           
2048-08-24 foo bar                                                                                                                                   
2048-08-24: Socket created...                                                                                                                        
---newtext :                                                                                                                                         
blabla foo 2048-10-23 this                                                                                                                           
2048-10-23 foo bar                                                                                                                                   
2048-10-23: Socket created...
```

Comment: I think this is the solution!! By changing the file name to the date format I want and replace "2019-06-26" in every log lines in every log in the folder by forloop!! Thanks a lot!!